# invalid last txid in stream

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

I am trying to configure hadoop namenode HA and resourcemanager HA as well. However, when I start namenode as standby, I got IllegalArgumentException as below:

```
=====================================================
 About to bootstrap Standby ID nn2 from:
            Nameservice ID: mycluster
         Other Namenode ID: nn1
   Other NN's HTTP address: http://my1.namenode.com:50070
   Other NN's IPC  address: my1.namenode.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8020
              Namespace ID: 1915209867
             Block pool ID: BP-740716617-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-1409206617148
                Cluster ID: CID-51cea219-ffe7-4a52-8a6c-fb83d501ccaa
            Layout version: -56
 =====================================================
 Data exists in Storage Directory /hadoop1/hadoop/hdfs/nn. Formatting anyway.
 14/11/05 16:41:20 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /hadoop1/hadoop/hdfs/nn has been successfully formatted.
 14/11/05 16:41:20 WARN common.Util: Path /hadoop1/hadoop/hdfs/nn should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
 14/11/05 16:41:20 WARN common.Util: Path /hadoop1/hadoop/hdfs/nn should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
 14/11/05 16:41:21 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
 java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid last txid in stream: http://my3.namenode.com:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=74823&storageInfo=-56%3A1915209867%3A0%3ACID-51cea219-ffe7-4a52-8a6c-fb83d501ccaa
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:317)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1306)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1395)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid last txid in stream: http://my3.namenode.com:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=74823&storageInfo=-56%3A1915209867%3A0%3ACID-51cea219-ffe7-4a52-8a6c-fb83d501ccaa
         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.<init>(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:101)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.chainAndMakeRedundantStreams(JournalSet.java:300)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumJournalManager.selectInputStreams(QuorumJournalManager.java:494)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.selectInputStreams(JournalSet.java:260)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.selectInputStreams(FSEditLog.java:1399)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.selectInputStreams(FSEditLog.java:1418)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.checkLogsAvailableForRead(BootstrapStandby.java:236)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.doRun(BootstrapStandby.java:203)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.access$000(BootstrapStandby.java:69)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby$1.run(BootstrapStandby.java:106)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby$1.run(BootstrapStandby.java:102)
         at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:102)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:312)
         ... 2 more
 14/11/05 16:41:21 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
 14/11/05 16:41:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
 /************************************************************
 SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at 
 ************************************************************/
```

All others are working well and I've checked hdfs-site.xml configuration for the problem but I couldn't find anything.

Please help me...

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried by formating Namenode first then configuring Namenode HA?

Comment: Yes we did... :-( When we access the specific data, the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Restart :

```
./sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode
```